# SQL Server Memory for Backup Buffer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

In  SQL Server 2012 memory for backup buffer comes from buffer pool or non buffer pool (VAS)? Is this behavior changed between SQL server 2008 R2 and SQL 2012?

EDIT: Does MAX Server Memory configuration setting now controls memory for backup buffer? Historically, this was coming out of MemToLeave (or Virtual Address Space) outside SQL Server buffer pool?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2012 nothing comes from buffer pool anymore, except data pages. This is a change from SQL Server 2008R2. See [Memory Manager surface area changes in SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlosteam/memory-manager-surface-area-changes-in-sql-server-2012). The buffer pool is just another client of the Memory Manager client for allocations, just like any other memory consumer. So the question is basically [unasked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question) in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Remus, my question should be does max server memory now controls memory for backup buffer?...
Historically this was coming out of memtoleave (or  virtual address space)....If I read late great Ken Henderson's book "SQL Server Practical TroubleShooting" it was mentioned but again that book was SQL 2005 era.

Comment: afaik max server memory does not account for backup buffers.

Comment: ... even in 2008 (if I'm reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/01/28/how-it-works-sql-server-backup-buffer-exchange-a-vdi-focus.aspx) correctly) the buffers for backup operations did not come from the buffer pool.