# How to plan bring down the space used by databases to as low as possible

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2014, compression

Per our security breaks and guidelines when a database grow too big that it cant meet the requirements where it cannot be restored under a given RTO we need to plan on achieving same:-

Based on your experiences i would need some guidance and help here:-

Some insights on the database in question -

> Total space --> Right click database-properties -> **size = 10TB**
>
> What seems free in above -->  Right click database-properties -> **space
> Available = 5 TB**

```
This database is an OLTP and critical one as it goes through lot of DUI operations throughout with heavy usage of TempDB
```

I have listed out TOP 10 tables with space and index usage:-

All top 5 as pulled are

- `partitioned` table with billion and million rows over 700 partitions
  in single table
- Above tables have `PAGE` compression enabled
- Above tables have less than 3 indexes in most of them but compression
  at index level shows `NONE`

For backup we do use compression with third party tool like idera to reduce size yet it crosses the threshold. Backup size is approx 1.9 TB for full backups. We do have diff and tran log backups as well.

I am little hesitant to go that shrinking route as it may impact performance but please help me with any ideas but else can be done to bring the space down?

Can we split few large table to their own separate database? If yes what is the catch?

Much appreciate all your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll echo SqlWorldWide on the point about data types. The article they linked has a few good examples, but there are a lot more less-obvious areas to check too.

I've written a script [sp_sizeoptimiser](https://github.com/LowlyDBA/dba-multitool/blob/master/docs/sp_sizeoptimiser.md) to help automatically identify a lot of them. Even if you don't use it, the areas it covers are worth looking into:

#### Data Types

- Time based data types
- Unspecified VARCHAR length
- Mad VARCHAR Max
- NVARCHAR data type
- FLOAT and REAL data types
- BIGINT as IDENTITY
- NUMERIC or DECIMAL with 0 scale
- Enum columns not implemented as foreign key

#### Architecture

- Default fill factor
- Number of indexes
- Inefficient indexes
- Sparse columns
- Heap tables

Details for each of these is in the documentation linked above.

Preferably, I'd run this on a non-production copy of the database if possible, however it doesn't do any heavy lifting under the hood, so should be OK to run on production as well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all the points above and this is not a complete answer but I cannot put these as a comment.

**In order to reduce size which will eventually make your restore quicker:**

1. Check compression at table/heap and also for each index
2. Archive/Purge old data
3. Choosing the correct data type will involve a lot of work. Read this [Saving disk space by choosing the correct data type](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/saving-disk-space-by-choosing-the-correct-data-type) by Eduardo Pivaral
4. Can you move objects to a different database?

**Can you make the restore faster?**

Few articles for your reference:

1. [Faster Restores: Best Practices to Increase Speed](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/backup-and-recovery/faster-restores-best-practices-to-increase-speed/) by Grant Fritchey
2. [How to Make SQL Server Backups and Restores Faster](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/how-to-make-sql-server-backups-and-restores-faster/) by Brent Ozar
3. [Why is restore slower than backup](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sqlskills-sql101-why-is-restore-slower-than-backup/)by Paul Randal
4. [Speed-up RESTORE DATABASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937792/speed-up-restore-database)
5. [Improve Restore Speed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131693/improve-restore-speed)